# User input from main window c#

Tags: c#, user-input, prompt

How can I get a prompt on the main window using c# to ask for user input? I tried

```
 Console.Writeline("write something");
```

&

```
 string input = Console.Readline();
```

but these commands do not display anything on my main window. I have an image on there, could the display of the Console prompt be behind it?

I want to have the user input used in a method outside of the main() method.

Comment: Are you referring to a console app or a windows form app?

Comment: I assume you refer to a Form or a Window when you refer to your "Main Window", not a Console panel. In that case, the method `Console.WriteLine` won't display anything.

Comment: It is a windows presentation foundation (wpf)

Answer (score 6):

The `Console` is only useful for console projects.  If this is a winform project, there's no (visible) console to access.

Instead, you want to look at [`MessageBox`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show) for [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx)

Comment: so there is no way to prompt for user input using a non-console project?

Comment: @user1773489 Sure there is, you're just not doing it correctly.  You don't use the console in a winform app, you use the form itself.  You add textboxes or combo boxes or other types of controls in which the user can provide information.

Comment: my project is a wpf project type, do i still use the same to get user input?

Comment: @user1773489 - Pretty much.  You use a slightly different version of the class for it than the one I originally linked, but it should behave close to the same.  I edited the answer to link directly to the documentation.